# How to export a .sid image as high DPI .tiff or .bmp from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, export, mrsid

I have 2 50 cm resolution areal photographs in .sid format.
How can I export these layers as a regular image format (like tiff or bmp) which I can then open in any simple picture viewer program?

I've tried saving a map, but that reduces the image resolution. I need to resulting image to retain it's original resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Raster -> Convert -> Translate` to jpg format should do what you want.

Comment: thanks, when I did that I got this error message:

ERROR 4: `C:/../rml-04.sid' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognised as a supported dataset name. 

GDALOpen failed - 4 
`C:/../rml-04.sid' does not exist in the file system, 
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.

Comment: Have you used relative paths? Or some blanks or non-ASCII-characters in the path to the file? You can change the commandline manually before starting the operation.